# How to downgrade to a previous Node version

Tags: node.js

I want to downgrade my Node version from the latest to `v6.10.3`.

But nothing has worked so far. Tried NVM and it gives an error as well by saying that the `make` command is not found. How can I downgrade Node?

Comment: it looks like your package has been installed, but not added to the PATH. add path to  your package and all will work fine

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11562 has the details, why to downgrade NodeJs to v16.13.0

Answer (score 704, accepted):

**Warning:**
This answer does not support Windows OS

You can use `n` for node's version management. [There](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) is a simple intro for `n`.

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 6.10.3
```

this is very easy to use.

then you can show your node version:

```
$ node -v
v6.10.3
```

---

For windows [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is a well-received tool.

Comment: In this [article](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm) recommend to clean the npm cache first, but it works fine as above for me on mac. Command `sudo npm cache clean -f`

Comment: didn't work for me in mac - says `The operation was rejected by your operating system.` Had to use `brew install n`

Comment: tried the same way, it does download but not installed, showing the older version on centos

Comment: For Windows use this: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows to setup `nvm` and control Node version via it.

Comment: If you get a permission error, this is helpful: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/416#issuecomment-417808320

Comment: But how do I select a specific version? it’s not clear, there are 2 lines on your first suggestion

Comment: @ofer2980, to make it work finally I did ```sudo n lts``` to demote to the last LTS and it fixed my issue. In general ```n <version>``` does the job

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu! Thanks for this.

Comment: this is not helpful at all. the question is how to downgrade, not switch version

Comment: How do you change the active version? I installed it fine but cant change the active version

Comment: @GrantSingleton Same. This solution for Mac will install the version you specify but it will not automatically make it the active version. OP should update the answer

Comment: @IanS I ended up just using brew to uninstall the version I had and install the version I needed. I would have loved for n to be able to switch the active version.

Comment: @GrantSingleton I actually did the same thing yesterday. I brew uninstall node then used brew to install the new version, unlink the old version, link the new one, etc. I agree, but this has made me consider using brew much more. 'n use' would not switch to the new version of node even though n could download it. Perhaps the n and brew conflict in certain areas.

Comment: `n` didn't work for me either, but `nvm use <version>` did - e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45632540/13488316

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11562 has the details, why to downgrade NodeJs to v16.13.0

Comment: Why would you use this? `nvm` is the standard node versioning tool.

Comment: @GrantSingleton The issue is with the path. If you brew install node and then install n and use n to install a different node version, the active node version will be the one installed by brew since the brew path has priority. You can update the path to node in your bash or zshrc file to use the one installed by n, or can simply brew uninstall node after you installed the lower node version with n.

Comment: Would be great if you included the option for windows as well. Don't know how this is the chosen answer if all the people using windows are excluded.

Comment: use sudo in case anyone is facing access issue
sudo npm install -g n

Answer (score 181):

For windows:

Steps

1. Go to `Control panel> program and features>Node.js` then **uninstall**
2. Go to website: https://nodejs.org/en/  and download the version and **install**.

Comment: For those looking for an older version, these are found here, https://nodejs.org/dist

Comment: There was a somewhat long list of download options, like .zip folders, .msi and .gz files and I wasn't sure which one to download. I have a Windows 64 bit device, installing the file ending in "x64.msi" and running it worked for me.

Answer (score 176):

**Determining your Node version**

```
node -v  // or node --version
npm -v   // npm version or long npm --version
```

**Ensure that you have `n` installed**

```
sudo npm install -g n // -g for global installation
```

**Upgrading to the latest stable version**

```
sudo n stable
```

**Changing to a specific version**

```
sudo n 10.16.0
```

*Answer inspired by this [article](https://www.surrealcms.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm.html).*

Comment: After this I had to close the terminal and restart the Mac. Thank you, it was very helpful.

Comment: Don't need to restart - just exit and open a new terminal session.

Comment: `sudo: n: command not found`

Comment: You need to download n first, using command mentioned within the answer: `sudo npm install -g n // -g for global installation`

Comment: in case of ```sudo: n: command not found``` use this 
```sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n ``` e.g:  ```sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/608661/command-not-found-when-executing-node-js-n-package-on-sudo

Comment: does it work for the most used OS ?

Comment: sudo: n: command not found

Answer (score 67):

In Mac there is a fast method with **brew**:

```
brew search node
```

You see some version, for example:   ***node@10 node@12 ...*** Then

```
brew unlink node
```

And now select a before version for example node@12

```
brew link --overwrite --force node@12
```

Ready, you have downgraded you node version.

Comment: I've gotten `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node@12`

Comment: The error means `node@12` has been installed yet. `brew install node@12` and then do run the link command.

Comment: Interesting that node@12 existed when running brew search node, but couldn't link until after running brew install node@12 as @Fanchen Bao mentioned.

Answer (score 48):

***This may be due to version incompatibility between your code and the version you have installed.***

In my case I was using **v8.12.0** for development (locally) and installed latest version **v13.7.0** on the server.

So using **nvm** I switched the node version to v8.12.0 with the below command:

```
> nvm install 8.12.0 // to install the version I wanted

> nvm use 8.12.0  // use the installed version
```

**NOTE:** *You need to install nvm on your system to use nvm.*

*You should **try this solution before** trying solutions like installing **build-essentials** or **uninstalling the current node version** because you could switch between versions easily than reverting all the installations/uninstallations that you've done.*

Answer (score 29):

For windows 10,

- Uninstalling the node from the "Add or remove programs"
- Installing the required version from https://nodejs.org/en/

worked for me.

Comment: How do you install from that page? I found a lot of different files listed, like .zip and .7z files and a folder win-x64 with .exe and .zip files. Do I need to download the zip and extract and then run something, or just download and run the .exe?

Comment: running .exe should do fine.

Comment: I actually downloaded the .msi file and that worked for me. I guess it is the file extension for installers. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 23):

```
 curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
 sudo npm install -g n
 sudo n 10.15
 npm install
 npm audit fix
 npm start
```

Answer (score 20):

If you're on **Windows** I suggest manually uninstalling node and installing [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation) to handle your node installation. `choco` is a great CLI for provisioning a ton of popular software.

Then you can just do,

```
choco install nodejs --version $VersionNumber
```

and if you already have it installed via chocolatey you can do,

```
choco uninstall nodejs 
choco install nodejs --version $VersionNumber
```

For example,

```
choco uninstall nodejs
choco install nodejs --version 12.9.1
```

Comment: If you want to stick always to the **Node LTS** version (which might be the reason for the desired downgrade), then use the Chocolatey [nodejs-lts](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs-lts) package instead. This offers the advantage to keep up-to-date with the latest supported LTS version.

Answer (score 18):

If you are on macOS and are not using NVM, the simplest way is to run the installer that comes from node.js web site. It it clever enough to manage substitution of your current installation with the new one, even if it is an older one. At least this worked for me.

Comment: Here is the official link with all node versions ever https://nodejs.org/dist/ You can use `CTRL+F` (`CMD+F` on Mac) to find exactly the version You need. Download the `.pkg` file if You are using a Mac and You are ready to go! :)

Answer (score 16):

Try using the following commands

```
//For make issues 
sudo apt-get install build-essential

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.4/install.sh | bash

//To uninstall a node version 
nvm uninstall <current version>

nvm install 6.10.3

nvm use 6.10.3

//check with 
node -v
```

Comment: notice: this installs ```nvm``` - a service that lets you have multiple node versions installed on you computer, and to set a node version for each project/folder

Answer (score 11):

Steps to downgrade to node8

```
brew install node@8
brew link node@8 --force
```

if warning remove the folder and files as indicated in the warning then again the command :

```
brew link node@8 --force
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly - also the advantage is - you then have proper updates through brew but only for the selected release. You could have issues during the 'link' stage if you have leftovers from previous installations but you will be pointed where so it is easy to clean.

Comment: `brew link node@8 --force --overwrite` solved the problem

Answer (score 11):

For windows users, you guys can downgrade using following commands.

**npm uninstall -g node**

**npm install -g node@version**

@version is your specified version, example : 12.22.3(little old)

Can find node releases here https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 9):

I have used **brew** in mac to downgrade the node

follow the steps you will have the result:

1. brew search node (here you can see the version eg: node@10, node@12, node@14)
2. brew unlink node
3. brew install <  node version > (eg: node@12)
4. brew link --overwrite node@12

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple solution

1. Go to this link and download & install the suitable nvm setup on your computer
   https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
2. Type `nvm list` to get list of installed node versions
3. Type `nvm install <node-version>`
4. Type `nvm use <version>`

here we go you got node version you want.

Browse here to find node versions => https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 7):

If you are using **nvm**, following are the ways -

```
1. nvm install node_version
2. nvm use --delete-prefix node_version
```

For more insights, see this image -
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu:

```
nvm list
nvm use <version>
```

nvm list // Shows all the versions on your machine. Of course have your version installed.

nvm use  // Use this version

Answer (score 4):

In case of **windows**, one of the options you have is to uninstall current version of Node. Then, go to the [node website and download the desired version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) and install this last one instead.

Answer (score 4):

it seems to be a compatibility issue, run

`sudo n 14`

then npm install or yarn install again. It will work

Answer (score 2):

WINDOWS: Best way that you can do it and to not lose time.

1. Go to control panel
2. Uninstall Program
3. Uninstall node
4. Then go and find the version that you want to install, install it from the beginning.

Link with node versions: https://nodejs.org/uk/blog/release/

Comment: Hi, your answer probably is acceptable, but other solutions make possible to pick a different version from time to time, without uninstalling anything

Answer (score 1):

The Node.js team suggests to use the following [Node.js version managers](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/install#using-a-node-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm) to switch between different versions of Node:

**OSX or Linux:**

- [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
- [n](https://github.com/tj/n)

**Windows:**

- [nodist](https://github.com/nullivex/nodist)
- [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

I personally made good experiences using "nvm-windows" on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

I had to downgrade node to v10.16.0

```
sudo n 10.16.0

nvm use v10.16.0
```

this solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I too wanted to downgrade my node version (v18.13.0) to a stable version(v16.10.0). So I followed these steps in my windows OS:

1. First I installed nvm to my computer, cause I hadn't installed it. Go through this [link](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases). And I downloaded `nvm-setup.exe` one. Choose your suitable version. After downloading the setup file, launch the installation wizard and follow the on-screen directions to install nvm.
2. Then add the nvm installation directory to your system's `PATH` environment variable. Like: `C:\Users\damik\AppData\Roaming\nvm`
3. Next you can type `nvm` in your cmd and you can clarify the installation of nvm.
4. Then uninstall the current version of Node.js. i.e.: `nvm uninstall v18.13.0`. First check your node.js and add relevant version here.
5. Now Node.js has been uninstalled, you can install the version you want using this command: `nvm install v16.10.0` . Please install the relevant version here.
6. After the installation is complete, run the following command to make the version you just loaded the default Node.js version. `nvm use v16.10.0`
7. This command will make the present shell session's version the default. You can use the `nvm alias default v16.10.0` to make this version the default for all new shell sessions:
8. Check your node version by `node -v`. And now it's all ok ;)

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything new to the existing answers. When answering a question that is  6 years old, consider whether your answer gives any new information.

Comment: @miken32 he said his solution is for windows and the accepted solution was for linux

Comment: @EfeOmoregieElijah And there are 20 other answers besides the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Mac:
The answer is using the 'HomeBrew'

1. Open terminal and write command `brew search node` (results like: node@16, node@20, etc)
2. `brew unlink node`
3. `brew link node@20` (you can use other version which is already installed in you system or install required version)

Answer (score -1):

use `nvm` from [this](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) link and install it. then use `nvm install <version name>` of your desired node version to install it. Finally write `nvm use <version name>` on your terminal to switch to your desired version number.