# NPM node-sass installation fails

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, node-sass

I am trying to install node-sass in a project, which perfectly builds and runs on my pc but on my surface I am having major issues when trying to install the packages.

Note: I have tryed reinstalling and rebuilding the project several times.

Summary of the error:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Max-T\Documents\Sources\StaffMangerV2\black-dashboard-pro-react-v1.0.0\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Max-T\\Documents\\Sources\\StaffMangerV2\\black-dashboard-pro-react-v1.0.0\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Max-T\Documents\Sources\StaffMangerV2\black-dashboard-pro-react-v1.0.0\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Max-T\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-30T10_05_01_386Z-debug.log
```

package.json => https://hastebin.com/azetegukes.pl
too much coode so I had to paste it elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried using yarn ? For most of the times yarn solved my problem for this.

Comment: Have you checked your npm config file? Is it correct because sometimes it gets corrupt and cause such issues. You can run npm run --config

Comment: @Mohit Tryed that, but the output seems fine to me => [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/xojopitugi.sql)

Comment: @RehanSattar Also tryed that before and now again, with a complete error log => [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/zevahuxoyo.makefile)

Comment: USE `NODE VERSION 10`, it will work, TO USE MULTIPLE NODE VERSION ON SAME PC,YOU CAN USE `NVM`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're using Node 12, and node-sass needs to be at least 4.12 to support that version https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixed the installation bug, but I am still ending up with the same error in the browser => [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/inatoregex.cs)

Comment: That looks like a separate question

Comment: actually true ... so I will ask a new one.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that each Node version has a specific required node-sass version, more info here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: Also worth  mentioning the [node version manager](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) so you can quickly switch between node versions to run legacy projects!

Comment: @adamdport Thanks! `nvm` is a cool tool to quickly switch between different npm and node versions without messing things up.

Answer (score 24):

If anyone runs into this lately... the easiest fix is to replace **node-sass** with just **sass** in your dependencies. It's the more recently maintained version and I only had to change 1 line of code with how it's initialized and all of my existing code was already compatible.

There are more details at https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated under *How to migrate*.

Comment: you are best. you saved me. thanks buddy.

Comment: Awesome ! I have to downgrade my node version to  14 using nvm. but yes it worked

Comment: This is also probably a more future-proof approach, as __node-sass is being deprecated__ per the linked doc above.

Answer (score 18):

## Don't use node-sass anymore

`node-sass` is deprecated. Instead use the new version which is `sass`.

You can uninstall the old and install the new one with this command

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

Comment: Totally agree. I used node-sass with laravel-mix, but now node-sass isn't in list of required dependencies.

Comment: Finally. I always struggled with it because of `node-gyp` build errors on windows and in alpine linux build containers. Until now the solution was to use node14 and python2 and vs-2017 build tools on windows.  There are many resources what to do in case of errors but none gave the hint to replace it. thanks mate!

Answer (score 7):

try this command it works for me

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Comment: I have no way to verify that at this point, but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, `-g` was not required.

Answer (score 3):

After more than 2 hours of trying all sorts of ways (cleaning npm cache, deleting node_modules, trying to install with global switch `-g`, etc.) to install node-sass and failing every time, I finally changed the mirror to china and it immediately worked for me!! (I know it kinda doesn't make any sense, considering the error I was getting)

Just for reference, this was the error I was receiving before it finally worked:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-06T13_56_56_768Z-debug.log
```

My Node version: v12.18.0
node-sass version in package.json: "^4.14.0"

I changed the mirror as stated in the [node-sass npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#install-from-mirror-in-china).

```bash
npm install -g mirror-config-china --registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org
npm install node-sass
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps fro replacing **node-sass** with **sass** which resolved my exact issue:

1. First remove 'node-sass'. Go to your package.json (remove it from dependency)
2. Than, remove package-lock.json file and node_modules
3. npm install
4. npm install sass --save

'npm start' would be your next step

Answer (score 0):

The best option would probably be to replace `node-sass` lib with `sass` one.
But in our case I fixed that by installing `nvm` and setting local node version to 14.17.6
My node-sass version is 4.14.1