# npm install node-sass command fail

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have ran the command `npm install node-sass`,and get a mistake as follow:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\votingComputePlantformFrontEndWeb\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
```

I have tried `npm install node-sass@4.5.0`, then I get

> npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

Comment: can you try running `npm i node-gyp` first, then `npm install node-sass@4.5.0`

Comment: I tried the `npm i node-gyp` and `npm install node-sass@4.5.0`,then I get the same error as above.

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623072/npm-node-sass-installation-fails

Answer (score 1):

https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

According to sass blog, node sass has been deprecated, and you should use dart sass.
Personally, I installed 'sass' instead of 'node-sass', and it worked regardless of Python.

```
npm install sass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. Your tar is outdated. To fix this issue run this command :-

```
npm i tar -g
```

and enter ok. Now your problem of `npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported,` and will not receive security updates. will be fixed.

Comment: I have ran this command `npm i tar -g ` and it was success,then I run command `npm install node-sass@4.5.0`,however,**I have get the same error as above**.What should I do to solve that promblem