# NPM node-sass build fails

Tags: node-sass

I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623072/npm-node-sass-installation-fails), [this](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1980), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51658389/cant-install-node-sass/51821030), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version/50287454#50287454), and [this](https://githubmemory.com/repo/Colt/webpack-demo-app/issues/10). I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node, n, npm, and nvm. I was able to get it to run on node version 14, however I need to use node version 16.13.

This seems to be telling me node version 16.13 is incompatible with node-sass v6.0.1. However, my team runs these versions without issue. I need to run the same versions as my team otherwise I can't really contribute.

Error output is [here](https://gist.github.com/Brayheart/fa6206e0c2dab42f550b37e6dda8dc4e).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your running on the newer Apple Silicon from the `arm64` arch lines in the log. Node-sass does not currently support that architecture. I'm guessing the sudo might have dropped you down into that Intel emulation layer and faked it out enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I didn't figure this out sooner.

If anyone ends up looking for this answer: I did move past this error with the `sudo` command