# gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe`

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, msbuild, npm-install

I'm getting the following error when I run my Jenkins job. I've installed MSBuild 15 and 17 and specified the correct path.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Where the issue is. Thanks.

```
(x86)\Jenkins\workspace\POS4> npm install
> pos4@1.0.10 install C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\POS4
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\POS4>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\POS4\build\..\build\Release\binding.node
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\POS4\build\binding.vcxproj(20,3): 

**error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Micr
osoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file
 exists on disk.**

gyp ERR! build error

**gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1**

gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite a common issue faced by users who build on a Windows based operating system. A `node-gyp` error means that a native module has failed to build. IMHO there has never been one single answer that has directly solved this issue in my experience. However below is a checklist I would suggest to follow if anyone else comes across `node-gyp` errors. You may have already tried these but just leaving it for reference.

- Install windows build tools using `npm install --global windows-build-tools`. This will enable compiling of native node modules and is courtesy of [felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools). Build tools include items like Python and Visual C++ packages (Python 2.7 seems to be the preferred one by [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp))
- Configure node-gyp to generate the appropriate build files for your project using `node-gyp configure` or `node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2015` in your case since you mentioned that you have installed a MSBuild 15 and 17. It would be better to stick to one and configure `node-gyp` to it (Go through [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) for more available commands such as `rebuild`)
- Ensure your `npm config` path for *Python* is set correctly. If you installed the build tools manually or using the link mentioned above ensure that your `npm config` points to a valid installation directory

  > These are just for reference and if I come across any more I will add them here as juggling `node-gyp` on Windows machines is something I have had trouble in the past and currently.

> This error is also commonly thrown for errors caused by native node modules such as SQLite since native bindings are unable to be found.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you're not working with Node 12 as node-gyp then will fail. Version 11.15.0 is the latest working version.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is the correct answer to the problem and immediately fixed it.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. I was getting the following:

`gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: \`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe\` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\\Projects\\quotes.webui\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\lib\\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763`

Comment: And what about versions 14+? So it won´t work for future Node versions?

Answer (score 6):

Try to downgrade your Node version to 11.15.0, because it is the latest working version.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287454/2513295) by [@aircraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6523163/aircraft) that states the following:

> You can use `n` for node's version management. [There](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) is a simple intro for `n`.
>
> ```
> $ npm install -g n
> $ n 6.10.3
> ```
>
> this is very easy to use.
>
> then you can show your node version:
>
> ```
> $ node -v
> $ v8.11.1
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This solved for me when I downgrade the node from 13 to ver 11 with latest npm and VS.

Answer (score 1):

I got this in windows env too. However, in linux it is fine. So I just copied the node_moduels from linux to windows.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanna chip in here as I just happened to resolve this. Make sure to downgrade your node.js to a recommended version of node. I was on current and that was causing issues.