# node-gyp configure "binding.gyp not found (cwd: D:\MyProject) while trying to load binding.gyp"

Tags: ethereum, node-gyp

I searched many and installed all necessary packages they said,
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7

I have vs2017 installed in my win10 pc, I am using last versions of nodes tools

```
node -v //8.12.0
npm -v //6.4.1
```

I tried remove nodejs and reinstall to start fresh install but stuck in this step each,

here my **.npmrc** content;

```
strict-ssl=false
node_gyp=node C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
msvs_version=2015
python=C:\Python27\python.exe
GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
```

ss of powershell, (node-gyp configure)
[image]

it looks for a file called 'binding.pyp'
If I add that file manually errormessage changes.. but other examples dont create any file they just install packges and run..

How can I fix this I searched on net many and did all advices(install ms build tools set msvs version 2017)

Comment: Hi. I have come across similar issues whenever it comes to building native modules with `node-gyp`. I compiled a small list of things that you could check. I know this is not a definite nor direct answer but if you come across anything that can be added please drop a comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089305/gyp-err-stack-error-c-program-files-x86-msbuild-14-0-bin-msbuild-exe/52294449#52294449