# Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

i am trying to install all dependencies using `npm install` command, but while installing it i am getting error like below :

```
ling source file ..\src\threaded_callback_invokation.cc)
c:\applatest\applatest\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1478): warning C4996: 'node::MakeCallback': was declared deprecated (comp
iling source file ..\src\threaded_callback_invokation.cc) [C:\appLatest\appLatest\node_modules\voicemeeter\node_modules
\ffi\build\ffi_bindings.vcxproj]
  c:\users\alliancetek\.node-gyp\10.15.0\include\node\node.h(176): note: see declaration of 'node::MakeCallback' (compi
  ling source file ..\src\threaded_callback_invokation.cc)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\appLatest\appLatest\node_modules\voicemeeter\node_modules\ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-linux@1.3.1 (node_modules\7zip-bin-linux):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-linux@1.3.1: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 7zip-bin-mac@1.0.1 (node_modules\7zip-bin-mac):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 7zip-bin-mac@1.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ffi@2.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ffi@2.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alliancetek\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-05T10_40_31_378Z-debug.log
```

in many of solutions i got try `npm install node-gyp` or uninstall or install it again but in that i am getting same error.

Also try with this steps:

- Install the latest versions of Python (it may not be related), and "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017", and of course, Node.js and NPM;
- As Admin:
  $ cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm"
  $ npm install node-gyp
- $ npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
  Note that I have VS 2017, but configuring it as ver 2017 won't work. Not sure why.
- As Admin:
  $ npm install -g node-sass
  And finally, one last check:
  $ node-sass -v

and try with `npm install --production windows-build-tools` but getting no result by any option.

tried with every solution but none of the working. i have installed python with 2.7.15, vc++ building tools, visual studio 2017 and all required components.

I am finding solution from last 2 weeks please suggest me correct answer

Comment: Please specify which dependencies you are trying to install. If multiple try to isolate the package which fails to install.

Comment: my project is in aurelia js. so thats why i have added aurelia question. if i have added then it have some meaning @avrahamcool

Comment: i am only trying to install "npm install" command because without that i am not able to install any dependencies and i am facing issue in "npm install" command itself @Mathyn

Comment: If you run `npm install` you are installing dependencies based on a package.json part of the project. Please share this package.json with us.

Comment: here you can check my package.json file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tobs3ci886fm47p/pacakge.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 28):

1. run: `npm cache clean --force`
2. delete node_modules
3. delete packagelock.json and yarn.lock(if have)
4. run: `npm install`

Comment: i have follow same steps but getting same error. here my logs are putting in one file

Comment: you can check logs here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/txaccpwda6t7n5m/logs.txt?dl=0

Comment: Delete the ~/.node-gyp folder and then the ~/.npmrc file.  

Reboot your server and rerun npm install in your project folder  **and please check the server node version package.json file than what your local environment was running. So check what you are running locally with:**

Comment: and please refer this ,it will help you [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089305/gyp-err-stack-error-c-program-files-x86-msbuild-14-0-bin-msbuild-exe ]

Comment: i have delete "node-gyp" folder from path : 
C:\appLatest\appLatest\node_modules\npm\node_modules and delete "npmrc" from path "
C:\appLatest\appLatest\node_modules\npm\html\doc\files". let me know if i have choose wrong path.  i am not clear with version check concept. how can i check that?

Comment: for your given link, i have already check and tried but it is also not working for me :( i have no idea that what i am missing and where

Comment: have you specified any version in package.json like { 
  "engines" : { 
    "node" : "8.0.0 " 
  }
}  than make sure your current node version is which specified in packge.json  .than run npm install

Comment: you can check package.json file here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tobs3ci886fm47p/pacakge.txt?dl=0 because i have no any parameter like this

Comment: put "ffi": "*"  in package.json than try npm install

Comment: i have tried with this and getting another type of error : here you can find my logs : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbdtkgeighixkf8/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: A new package will do all of this for us now.

Make sure you have the sufficient permissions by running:

**Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force**

then run:

**npm install -g windows-build-tools**

wait for it to install and then run:

**window-build-tools**

and everything should be in its finest order.  if this won't work update your package.json modules with latest versions.

Comment: after install this command getting same error : you can check logs here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vu5cfuz5jxk9xe7/log_cors.txt?dl=0

Comment: i have tried with "npm install -g windows-build-tools" as your given steps but i am getting still same error. for the latest version module how can i update that all packages because i am not installing any packages to my project

Comment: I searched in github, and stackoverflow until i found your answer ! thank you a lot you saved my life :)

Comment: i tried same but still failed to run npm install my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60613405/npm-install-issues-found-during-obdx-android-app-development

Comment: no didnt work for me. everything is same as last one . this is my repo that have this error https://github.com/llighter/ionic-studycard

Answer (score 5):

None of these answers worked for me on Windows 10 and Node 13. I had to uninstall Visual Studio and Build Tools, and uninstall Node 13. Then, I deleted npm and npm-cache from Roaming, before reinstalling Node 11.6 and choosing to install Chocolately. It worked for me thereafter.

Comment: I faced the same on Win 10 - the problem was again the version of node. I installed a node  version manager for windows : https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Then I installed v. 10 (as this was for an Ang7 project, I had v. 12 before that):
nvm install 10
nvm use 10.0.0

And this resolved the problem. With the manager you can quickly switch node versions if you're working in multiple repos.

Comment: Mine worked after I downgraded to Node 10.x. Nothing else I tried actually worked.

Comment: yes this worked for me, apparently when i ticked the checkbox that asks to install chocolaty and other c++ libraries it downloaded whatever the heck was missing and i was able to do `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

- Run `npm install --production windows-build-tools` might take longer to install, worked for my friend

> OR

- Reinstalling nodeJs worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can try downgrading Node.js to an older version, i was using version **v14.16.1LTS**.
After switching to **v10.24.1** it worked.

To change your node version check [How to change to an older version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Remember to first remove your `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`

You can also try switching from yarn to npm or npm to yarn.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command in cmd with administrator priviledges:

```sh
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2017
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.