# npm install issues found during obdx android app development

Tags: android, node.js, visual-studio, npm-install

1. installed node -v[10.17.0]
2. npm -v[6.11.3]
3. Python -v[2.7.17]
   facing lots of issues during npm install inside _build folder
   Followed steps from OBDX Android app here : [ORACLE ANDROID LINK FOR OBDX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F12056_01/tech_docs/Oracle%20Banking%20Digital%20Experience%20Mobile%20Application%20Builder-Android.pdf)
   [image: node]

Comment: I think it's a problem with gyp use **npm install -g node-gyp** are you using window?

Comment: Yes, i am using windows

Comment: after above command if problem exist run **npm install -g windows-build-tools** ,hope this will fix the issue

Comment: i tried to reinstall VS build-tools after that npm install works fine but there are issues in . another command that i executed just after npm install 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666486/node-render-requirejs-obdx-business-platform-for-android-failed-to-execute-comma

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666486/node-render-requirejs-obdx-business-platform-for-android-failed-to-execute-comma  pls check this .... all issues went except one mentioned here