# YN0000: Resolution step error on React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am completely new to react and I hope you guys can help me with this problem. I have the latest node version installed. After entering npx create-react-app . on terminal this happens:

```
YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.1.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.1.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ nan@npm:2.14.0: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1.49m
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 18.74s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0007: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.9#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.9&hash=e8cd9e must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.6.4 must be built because it never did before or 
the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.4.7 must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:2.6.10 must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 22.8s
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 2.19m

Installing template dependencies using yarnpkg...
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ play@workspace:. doesn't provide @testing-library/dom@>=5 requested by @testing-library/user-event@npm:7.2.1
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 2.63s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 2.68s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 12.76s
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 18.18s
Removing template package using yarnpkg...

➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0002: │ play@workspace:. doesn't provide @testing-library/dom@>=5 requested by @testing-library/user-event@npm:7.2.1
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1.16s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0019: │ cra-template-npm-1.0.0-e8d1aa4189-1.zip appears to be unused - 
removing
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1.93s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
```

Node modules is not even on the folder. Help? Thanks!

Comment: What version of node are you using? I was just having trouble running create-react-app, and fixed it by downgrading node to v8.11.1. I ran `sudo n 8.11.1` and everything worked fine after.

Comment: I intalled the lastest lts version of node. I thought the latest version would be ideal lol. I'll try downgrading. Do you have a link for 8.11? Also, what is sudo n for windows? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can refer to this on downgrading node, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version. As for sudo on Windows, I'm not sure sorry! You might not even need it

Comment: Downgrading worked! I should have not upgraded in the first place lol. Thanks!

Comment: Since that worked, I've posted that as an answer here. Please mark it as accepted for visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and resolved it by downgrading the node version to something like v8.11.1.

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version) on how to downgrade node versions.