# Node Sass with apple m1, Big Sur and arm64

Tags: npm, gulp-sass, apple-m1

```
 Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Unsupported runtime (93)
 For more information on which environments are supported please see:
 https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
at module.exports (/Users/hhag/Desktop/test_gulp/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hhag/Desktop/test_gulp/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hhag/Desktop/test_gulp/node_modules/gulp-sass/index.js:166:21)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
```

this error occures when I start to use gulp. is there a solution for using gulp-sass with apple m1? thanks

Answer (score 121):

I also had issues installing `node-sass` on M1, and ended up using the opportunity to replace it with `sass`, as recommended on the LibSass deprecation notice.

https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

> If you’re a user of Node Sass, migrating to Dart Sass is straightforward: just replace node-sass in your package.json file with sass. Both packages expose the same JavaScript API.

As mentioned by [@Ti Hausmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860205/ti-hausmann) you can try with:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install --save-dev sass
```

The replacement was completely smooth, it worked on M1, and I couldn't notice any performance impact locally or on the CI.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I did `npm uninstall node-sass`, `npm install --save-dev sass`.

Comment: see an answer below from m_kos. it seems more sensible to just change dependencies in node-sass

Answer (score 93):

For npm > 6.9 you can switch your dependency to dart-sass/sass with just one line and from there just use sass as you would before.

`npm install node-sass@npm:sass`

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, non of the others above helped

Comment: tnx bro, it worked for me

Comment: Node v 16.13.0 and NPM v 8.1.4 here; worked like a charm 

Comment: This command gave me dependency tree errors, but a simple `npm i sass` worked.

Comment: `yarn add sass` worked for me.

Comment: This works for now, but I am not sure how it will behave once its in a Source Control system like git and peers who might be working on other machines, since lock file needs to be committed as well !

Comment: This worked on node v14.20.1, npm v6.14.16 without any further errors.

Answer (score 36):

I think, you are using an M1 Mac. And node-sass currently doesn't support it natively. See: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3033

For now you can set target arch for running it through Rosetta with:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install --target_arch=x64
```

Comment: Hi, Murart Corlu
It does work on local machine when i tries to build Image using Dockerfile it fails to install packages. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Am facing same issue using dockerfile. Can you please share your solution if you were able to resolve it

Comment: is there any workaround for docker @khizer

Comment: @KapilGupta are you able to resolve this issue somehow?

Answer (score 19):

I ran into the same error when developing a Vue.js project with node-sass.
I worked around this issue by downgrading to Node version 14.

I’ve done this with n, a Node’s version manager application. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287454.

Check which node version you’re using

```
$ node -v 
v16.3.0
```

Install n

`$ npm install -g n`

Get list of available Node versions you can install

```
$ n ls-remote --all
16.3.0
16.2.0
..
15.14.0
15.13.0
..
14.17.0
14.16.1
..
```

Install Node version 14

`$ sudo n install 14`

Comment: +1, Bear in mind if one had a previous installation of node using brew, one will have to uninstall the brew's node with `brew uninstall node` so the `n` node version takes effect

Comment: I don't want to downgrade node version, is there no other way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

1. Reinstall node to version 14 by downloading from here
   https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.0.0/
2. in your project folder run `npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: This is the answer that saved me thousand hours. Just downgrade to node 14 and problem is solved.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me after trying for ages!

Answer (score 6):

Just adding for completeness of the answer, that I came across this issue when using the serverless framework (https://www.serverless.com/).

I was receiving a node gyp build error using both Node 16 and 17.

Using nvm I installed node version 14 and this solved my issue.

The steps to fix were:

1. nvm install v14
2. nvm use 14

Then I was able to do a yarn command which installed and built correctly.

Comment: After downgrading from node 17 to node 14 solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

1. `yarn add sass` or `npm install sass`
2. replace  `"node-sass":`  with `"sass":`  in package.json
3. `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

---

Worked for me on my M1 MBP.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the official recomendation [per gulp-sass Issue #803](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/803) - Apple M1 Chip Support

Switch to the sass compiler: [Instructions](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#setting-a-sass-compiler)

**TL;DR:**

1. Install version 5 of node-sass that does not include a default Sass compiler:

`npm install sass gulp-sass --save-dev`

or, Yarn

`yarn add sass gulp-sass --save-dev`

2. Explicitly set your compiler in your gulpfile:

`const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));`

or, for ES6 modules

```
import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
```

Answer (score 3):

Switching to Sass works just great in m1. As pointed in the top answers. And we should always be using sass in place of node-sass now as it's deprecated.

Here I want to point to one case that some may fall in. That if it's the case I think that would save you some time.

#### Case

You go and remove node-sass through `npm uninstall` or even by doing `npm install node-sass@npm:sass` as pointed in the second answer. You removed `node-modules` and `package-lock.json`.
**And still having the same problem and somehow `node-sass` is getting compiled.**

## Not working even after trying to install sass?

If so the case. Make sure to check your dependencies versions. A good chance some of them depends on node-sass on there old versions.

Ex:

```json
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "styles-loader": "^1.0.2"
```

update the version to latest =>

```json
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "styles-loader": "^3.0.0"
```

That should do it. And make sure to check all the dependencies that can depend on `node-sass` and update them.

If for some reason that still is a problem. You can try adding

```json
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "*"
  }
```

to `package.json`. I don't think it's necessary though.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me,

```
npm uninstall node-sass -g && npm cache clean -force && npm install node-sass
```

Answer (score 1):

I have struggle lot with issue my my brand new macOS Monterey M1 Chip Macbook Pro. None of solutions work except It's fix when I have set target arch for NPM installation using below command.

```
npm install --target_arch=x64
```

Answer (score 1):

The only command that worked for me was:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

### Yarn:

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add node-sass --dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide - https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass#setting-a-sass-compiler. It helped me a lot. Just make sure in the end that gulp-sass version is greater than 5.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).