# Error code 1 when installing npm packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

After playing around with nodeJs I have come back to my Craft CMS websites to work on other projects.

On executing "npm i", I was met by the below error

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
npm ERR! info sharp Using cached /Users/michaelbutler/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.8.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! (node:1501) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/common.cc:22:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/node.h:63:
npm ERR! In file included from /Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8.h:30:
npm ERR! /Users/michaelbutler/.node-gyp/16.13.1/include/node/v8-internal.h:492:38: error: no template named 'remove_cv_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'remove_cv'?
npm ERR!             !std::is_same<Data, std::remove_cv_t<T>>::value>::Perform(data);
npm ERR!                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR!                                      remove_cv
npm ERR! /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:710:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
npm ERR! template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
npm ERR!                                                  ^
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/michaelbutler/Sites/cardtwister-website/node_modules/favicons/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/michaelbutler/.npm/_logs/2021-12-07T11_44_09_876Z-debug.log
```

Is from a conflict with node versions. As I result, I have tried brew install node@14 to step down versions, but brew link did not seem to work / did not resolve this error.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

The issue seems to also occur when trying to install "Sharp" individually (i.e. npm install sharp)

Here is my package.json, as this will likely be required

```
   {
  "name": "doodle-craft-puppy",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://doodle-je@bitbucket.org/doodledevelopers/doodle-craft-puppy.git",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://doodle-je@bitbucket.org/doodledevelopers/doodle-craft-puppy.git"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "browsers": [
              "last 2 versions",
              "Explorer 10"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%"
  ],
  "description": "Doodle's Project Scaffold for craft",
  "author": "doodle",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "paths": {
    "src": {
      "scss": "./src/scss/**/*.scss",
      "images": "./src/images/",
      "fonts": "./src/fonts/*",
      "svgs": "./src/icons/svg/**/*.svg",
      "templates": "./templates/**/*.{html,twig}",
      "js": [
        "./src/js/app.js"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "base": "./web/",
      "css": "./web/build/css/",
      "images": "./web/build/images/",
      "fonts": "./web/build/fonts/",
      "svgs": "./web/build/icons/svg/",
      "js": "./web/build/js/"
    },
    "favicon": {
      "src": "./src/favicons/favicon.png",
      "dest": "./web/favicons/",
      "path": "/img/site/"
    },
    "craftConfig": "./config/"
  },
  "urls": {
    "live": "http://card-twister.com/",
    "local": "http://cardtwister-website:8888/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/register": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "barba.js": "^1.0.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^2.6.4",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.5",
    "browserify": "^16.5.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.16.7",
    "del": "^4.1.1",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-better-rollup": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-favicons": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-purgecss": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-size": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-svg-symbols": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-svgstore": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-tap": "1.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "smooth-scroll": "github:cferdinandi/smooth-scroll",
    "svgxuse": "^1.2.6",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-update": "^3.3.30",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
    "inuitcss": "^6.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "menuspy": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-rem": "^2.0.1",
    "sftp-sync-deploy": "^0.7.1",
    "vanilla-lazyload": "^16.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node Sass with apple m1, Big Sur and arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095626/node-sass-with-apple-m1-big-sur-and-arm64)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The dart sass suggestion has had no impact, nor has changing from node-sass to sass as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612707/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-with-uns

Comment: node-sass 4 (Used by gulp-sass 4) doesn't work with Node 16. See [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy). Maybe update to gulp-sass 5.

Comment: @GOTO0 thank you very much, this resolved the first error (which I have now removed from the above). This has made it clear to me that I'm experiencing two, not directly connected issues.