# node sass not supporting current env

Tags: reactjs, npm, nvm

I'm getting this error:

> error - ./public/styles/bootstrap.scss
> Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Node.js 14.x
> For more information on which environments are supported please see:
> https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v8.0.0

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "ncell_website",
    "description": "NZD website frontend developed with ReactJS, NextJS and Express",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Nagib Mahfuj <mahfujnagib@gmail.com>",
    "license": "SEE LICENCE at <a href='https://www.appsdone.com'>AppsDone</a>",
    "private": true,
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "export": "npm run build && next export"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
        "animated-scroll-to": "^2.0.10",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "cookie-machine": "^0.1.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
        "date-fns": "^2.17.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase": "^7.6.2",
        "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
        "jss": "^10.3.0",
        "localforage": "^1.7.3",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "lru-cache": "^6.0.0",
        "md5": "^2.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "next": "^9.4.4",
        "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
        "next-offline": "^5.0.3",
        "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-activity-detector": "^1.1.1",
        "react-awesome-slider": "^4.1.0",
        "react-content-loader": "^5.1.0",
        "react-date-range": "^1.1.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
        "react-id-swiper": "^4.0.0",
        "react-input-range": "^1.3.0",
        "react-jss": "^10.3.0",
        "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.8",
        "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
        "react-otp-input": "^2.3.0",
        "react-rating": "^2.0.5",
        "react-rating-stars-component": "^2.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-select": "^4.2.1",
        "react-slick": "^0.27.0",
        "recompose": "^0.30.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8"
    }
}
```

I'm using Node.js version 14. Tried installing latest caniuse-lite.

Comment: Node Sass is deprecated, use the official sass package "sass" and you'll likely be fine.  node-sass and node-gyp (which it relies on) create binaries for you system so you compile the sass and run things like rebuild sass.  While node-gyp is still maintained, the version node-sass relies on is likely ancient and armless - just like node-sass.

I found this SO which may help you as well -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68095626/node-sass-with-apple-m1-big-sur-and-arm64