# ng --version showing The current version of Node (16.8.0) is not supported by Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli, nvm

I just installed the latest version of **node(16.8)** using **nvm** and **angular/cli(12.2)**.

But when i run
`ng --version`

It shows the following:

**Warning: The current version of Node (16.8.0) is not supported by Angular.**

I tried to downgrade the node and  installed **node 14.15** but **ng** is not working anymore.

Should i ignore the warning and use **node 16**?.

Why is **ng** not working with **node 14.15**?.

PS: I am using nvm to manage the different node versions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Angular CLI with Node >=14 version. Command not working, because you switched to another nvm node version with it's own installed packages. You have to install angular cli again on your node 14.15. `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Can i ignore the cli warning and continue using node 16?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but you can try by your own risk.

Comment: Just use v14.xx

Answer (score 13):

```
nvm use <previous-version>
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
nvm use 16
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng version
```

This worked for me.

Comment: With one amendment. The node version should be higher than 16.14.
So eventually install this version 
 nvm install 16.14.2
then:
...
nvm use 16.14.x (or higher)
...

Answer (score 12):

Kindly go the the flowing link to install the compatible Node version supported by different Angular versions:

[Angular And Node.Js Compatibility](https://unpkg.com/browse/@angular/core@14.1.3/package.json)

Select the angular core version for checking it's compatibility as per your need as **shown in the below Image**:

[image: angular-core version compatibility]

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall latest node.js version from your system and install expected or lower version of node.js as per angular requirement.

https://angular.io/guide/setup-local

Comment: You don't have to uninstall node version from your computer. You may have several versions of npm and use the required one accordingly.
>> nvm use "required version"

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issue may comes in a situation where you shift between different node versions. That means when you uninstall an old version of node and install **Current/Latest** node version.

The reason for this issue that `Angular requires an active LTS or maintenance LTS version of Node.js`. Refer [Angular-setup-local](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) documentation.

Since you installed **Current/Latest** version of node you are getting above warning. To resolve this warning you can shift to LTS version of Node.js by following below steps.

**At this time LTS version of node is 18.17.1** Refer [Node Versions](https://nodejs.org/en)

- Install Node Version Manager (NVM) to change node version. Refer [How
  to downgrade to a previous Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-to-a-previous-node-version). Windows user use this [nvm-windows/releases assets](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)
- After that run `nvm install 18.17.1` to install LTS version
- Then run `nvm use 18.17.1` to switch to desired version
- Now run `node -v` to check node version - it should **v18.17.1**
- Finally run `ng v` you won't get above warning now.