# the current version of node (16.17.1) is not supported by angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Someone help me with this above context. I'm not able to resolve this issue

I tried downgrading the node.js version to the version which is supported by the angular but yet no luck.

Comment: Provide more details about your Angular version. You can also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090357/ng-version-showing-the-current-version-of-node-16-8-0-is-not-supported-by-an

Comment: Thank you @AleemS. Problem got solved by the link you shared!