# How to downgrade node version?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I want to downgrade my version using npm.
The current version is 16.13.1. I want to downgrade this to 12.0.1. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a version management tool (e.g. [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs), [volta](https://github.com/volta-cli/volta), [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)).

Comment: You can find detailed information here: [How to downgrade Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade to a previous Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-to-a-previous-node-version)

Answer (score 23):

use node version manager `nvm`, you can switch any node version that you want.

More details

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm

```
nvm install 14.15.5

nvm use 14.15.5
```

Use below command for all installed node versions

```
nvm list
```

Comment: While this is useful, a better answer would include an example with nvm to downgrade Node~

Comment: how can you tell its switched? current version is 20.9, so I ran > nvm install 16 then nvm use 16. "Now using node v16.0.0", however when i ng serve, i get an error from Node.js v20.9.0

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish that with Node Version Manager. Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installing-and-updating) first, and in a terminal:

```
nvm install 12.0.1
```

Then

```
nvm use 12.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `npm install -g node@version`.

So for example in your case it would be -> `sudo npm install -g node@12.0.1`

might have to force it with `--force` at the end.

Comment: I tried running that command - both with --force and without - I get a 404 error `GET https://registry.npmjs.org/16.20.2 - Not found`

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the local installation of node, to find out where is and delete

```
where node
```

Install nvm

[For Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

[For others](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases)

Show all the versions

```
nvm ls available
```

Install what you want

```
nvm install 12.0.1
nvm use 12.0.1
```

Check node version

```
node -v
```

*I have tried several ways and this works, hope it helps.*

Answer (score 0):

You could also install the [`node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node) npm module to change (upgrade or downgrade) the NodeJS version for the specific project.

Answer (score 0):

first check your node version

```
node -v
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
sudo n 14.6.0 (you can chnage version here as you want to move)
npm install (jst run after all)
```

now you can check the node and npm version by

```
 node -v
 npm -v
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the `n` package from npm. [Find it here.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

```
npm install -g n

n 10.16.0
n lts
```

> Simply execute `n <version>` to download and install a version of Node.js. If  has already been downloaded, n will install from its cache.

Answer (score -2):

I finally found a simple solution.

1. Uninstall the current Version
2. Download the version you want.

It works fine for me.

Thanks!