# how can I fix this problem npm error to install my react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/html-webpack-plugin: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 3):

Try clear the cache and install again

npm cache clear --force

npm install

you can try use **yarn** too.. because it uses backup sources.

Answer (score 1):

**This Will fix the issue:**

> - **npm config set fetch-retries 5**
> - **npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 600000**
> - **npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 1200000**
> - **npm config set fetch-timeout 1800000**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run an existing react project too, and I got the same errors while running: `npm install`

**I had node version 16.15.0 and I upgraded to version 18.1.0,**

I run `npm install` and everything was finally fine.

Check this out:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12330

**You may also revert to node version 16.4.16 and see if that works for you.**
[How to downgrade Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version)

Answer (score 0):

My friend I was facing the same problem as me and I found the solution
I hope it works out for you
*First Step* : Download Latest Version Of Node Js
*Second Step* : Download Npm Latest Version (Latest Version Important)
by **npm install -g npm@latest** in Cmd Or Terminal Visual Studio Code

> Then

Check Of in Cmd Or Terminal Visual Studio Code Any you Want It's Up To You
**node -v** => Should Display Number Represent Node Version
**npm -v**  => Should Display Number Represent Npm Version

> Then

Write ((**npx create-react-app app-name**) => Any Name You Want)
I hope with all my heart that this solution will work

Answer (score -1):

i recommande to work with yarn
npm install --global yarn
yarn create react-app my-app

else you need to clean the cache
npm cache clean --force   // clean the cache
npm cache verify          //verify the cache

npx create-react-app my-app // create you react app
npm i

Comment: Could you explain why he should use yarn?

Comment: speed:Yarn installs packages in parallel. Yarn is optimized to fetch and install multiple packages simultaneously. If you are installing five packages, and two are taking a long time to install, Yarn will go over and install the packages side by side.
On the other hand, NPM would install each package one at a time. security yarn check the resource of the package