# When I create react native project it's give me error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, error-handling, runtime-error

**my node and react native version**

```
react-native -v : 2.0.1
node -v : v16.16.0
```

**run cmd**

```
npx react-native init Loan --version 0.68.2
or
npx react-native init Loan
```

**its give me error like this**

```
 C:\Users\dp312>npx react-native init Loan --version 0.68.2 npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location-global` instead.
    This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in C:\Users\dp312\Loan
    'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file. Installing react-native@0.68.2...
    Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
    npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
    npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react-native: 10976: error:1408F119:SSL routines: ss13_get_record: decryption failed or bad rec ord mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ss13_record.c:677: npm ERR!
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!
    C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-01T12_48_16_254Z-debug-0.log
    Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.68.2
    at checkExecSyncError (node: child_process:828:11)
    at execSync (node: child_process: 899:15) at run (C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5) at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dp312\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node: internal/modules/cjs/loader: 1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader: 981:32) {
    status: 1,
    signal: null,
    output: null, null, null ],
    pid: 7772,
    stdout: null,
    stderr: null
    } Command `npm install --save --save-exact react-native@0.68.2` failed.
    C:\Users\dp312>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MoWw.png)

**or when I try to install any lib in project with npm its give me also error but when I run yarn it's install successfully**

[when run yarn cmd it's working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mycEo.png)

[when run npm it's give me like this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzJU9.png)

any one can give me solution and why this error is come

I'm just reset my pc after this error is come but before reset pc it's working properly I don't know why this error is come.

Comment: [Please post code, errors, etc s formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: what I send in text formate error img text ?

Comment: Those errors are all text; they can be added to the question as formatted text.

Comment: I will edit please check this

Comment: Check your firewall settings ;Windows Defender it whatever it’s called) first.

Comment: I don't understand what you say

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache and do a install again

`npm cache clear --force`

`npm install`

Or

`npm cache verify`

`npm install`

seems like a recurring problem with npm packages: [npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch http://registry.npmjs.org/accepts: Integrity verification failed for sha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308304/npm-err-invalid-response-body-while-trying-to-fetch-http-registry-npmjs-org-a)

[how can I fix this problem npm error to install my react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549479/how-can-i-fix-this-problem-npm-error-to-install-my-react-app)

Comment: where I install npm install administrator mode ??

Comment: If your react-native installation was completed you would do this on the folder, but I think you can just try to init react native again. If doen't work you can try update your node version to 18.13.0 or update your npm version with npm install -g npm@latest

Comment: npm install -g npm@latest is do in project or global ?

Comment: The -g flag means global is a short for --global

Comment: so I can intsall [npm install -g npm@latest ] as a administrator mode ??

Comment: No, in normal mode.

Comment: okay I will try

Comment: yes it will work but if I use [npx react-native init Loan] this cmd it's give me like this error[  cli.init(root, projectName);
      ^
TypeError: cli.init is not a function]

Comment: This problem is related here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72768245/typeerror-cli-init-is-not-a-function-for-react-native it seems you need remove old react-native-cli

Comment: in this ans no one is green tik answer