# stencil init ---> not ok -- TypeError: this.breakLines(...).flat is not a function

Tags: local, stencil-component, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

While setting up local in my machine(windows), I am getting following error on running "stencil init"

```
C:\Users>stencil init
not ok -- TypeError: this.breakLines(...).flat is not a function
Please visit the troubleshooting page https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/deploying-a-theme/troubleshooting-theme-uploads.
If this error persists, please visit https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues and submit an issue.
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade node to version 12.22.12 and it will work. The easiest way to do it is using NVM:

[How to downgrade Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version)

Comment: I can confirm, that this worked for me on a Mac running Big Sur, I was getting the same error.