# Downgrade Node Js version

Tags: node.js, windows, version, downgrade

I want to downgrade the NodeJs version to 16 as some of the dependencies I am using in my React app do not support NodeJs 17. I tried this method [(another post on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version)) also but this thing is not getting installed on my PC.

OS: Windows
[image]

Any sort of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use nvm (node version manager) to download the Node version 16, and then use it in your project. Which OS are you using?

Comment: The best is to uninstall nodejs completely from your PC and install nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm and nvm makes our life so easy to switch node versions easily.

Comment: Your OS is Linux / Windows / Mac?

Comment: Windows is not supported from `n` Just uninstall node.js and re-install the version you wanted. The error message you get is because the OS version check fails. `nvm` on the other hand is also not 100% compatible with windows.

Comment: I don't think downgrading to Node 16 is the correct approach, anyway. What are those dependencies that don't support a newer version of Node?

Answer (score 4):

Clearing the local installation of node, to find out where is and delete

```
where node
```

Install nvm

[For Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases)

[For others](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases)

Show all the versions

```
nvm ls available
```

Install what you want

```
nvm install 16.11.0
nvm use 16.11.0
```

Check node version

```
node -v
```

*I have tried several ways and this works, hope it helps.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use Node Version Manager(NVM).where you can downgrade or upgrade any node version. Please check

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Windows:
https://dev.to/skaytech/how-to-install-node-version-manager-nvm-for-windows-10-4nbi
Ubuntu:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: While this is useful, a better answer would have included an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (See link readme: Windows uses installer, Linux has a CLI copy+paste bash script).
2. Restart the shell (if it was open when installed) to register the new path.
3. If you want 14.18.1, for example: `nvm use 14.18.1`
4. If you don't have it installed, it'll let you know. In that case: `nvm install 14.8.1` -> repeat #3.
5. `node -v` to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs.org has previous releases versions in their distribution directory. Find the node version you need and install it.

https://nodejs.org/dist/

Answer (score -1):

n is the simplest package to manage your node versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/n

Comment: Not a answer! He is trying using `n`. `n` is not for Windows...