# ng test fails midway with "[karma-server]: UnhandledRejection"

Tags: angular, windows, google-chrome, karma-runner

Today when I ran ng test on a project on Karma 4.4.1, I got the following error `[karma-server]: UnhandledRejection` and the tests stopped midway - "Executed 26 of 1371". Chrome appears and then disappears and the tests stop.

```
12 07 2022 11:43:34.087:ERROR [karma-server]: UnhandledRejection
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is [to downgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-to-a-previous-node-version) to Node v14.

This is because Karma (or at least Karma 4.4.1) is incompatible with Node 15 and above - see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3570