# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule', in react native while integrating admob

Tags: android, react-native, expo, admob, ads

I am new to react native and I wants to monetize my app, so I am integrating Admob in react native, i created my app using `npx create-react-native-app` command, i tried to see youtube ,google, chatgpt, bard but nothing's working and this is my last hope please help me here is my code,

app.json

[image]

Copybase.js --- the file where I am testing my ads but nothing showed up from last 2 days

```
import { Animated, Dimensions, Image, Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import { useThContext } from '../reducon/context';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
import { BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER : 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx';

export default Copybase = ({ navigation }) => {

  const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const bgColor = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;


  const handlePressIn = () => {
    Animated.spring(animation, {
      toValue: 0.97,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(bgColor, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }
  const handlePressOut = () => {
    Animated.spring(animation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(bgColor, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Linking.openURL(info.link);
  }


  const { info } = useThContext();

  const backgroundColor = bgColor.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['#749b38', '#648630'],
  })

  return (
    <View>
      <Header navi={navigation} text={'BASE LAYOUT'} BackButton={true} />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={info.image} />
        <Pressable onPressIn={() => { handlePressIn() }} onPressOut={() => { handlePressOut() }}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.copyButton, { transform: [{ scale: animation }], backgroundColor: backgroundColor }]}>
            <Text style={styles.copyButtonText}>COPY LAYOUT</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <BannerAd
        unitId={TestIds.BANNER}
        size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
        requestOptions={{
          requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9',
  },
  image: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: 300,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  copyButton: {
    marginTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#749b38',
    padding: 12,
    borderRadius: 3,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.16,
    shadowRadius: 1.51,
    elevation: 6,
  },
  copyButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 18,
  }
});
```

the error that i am facing ----

```
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:null in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:null in handleError
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in createErrorHandler
at node_modules\expo\build\errors\ExpoErrorManager.js:null in <anonymous>
at node_modules\@react-native\js-polyfills\error-guard.js:null in ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard
at node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:null in guardedLoadModule
at http://192.168.29.76:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in metroRequire
at http://192.168.29.76:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in global
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same error and the problem was using `expo go` to run my app. What you must do is after building your app using `eas` build, you must download your built app from `eas` and then install it on your device or emulator. then run your dev server from vs code and run your downloaded app. please refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUFHXsBcW6w&ab_channel=Expo) from youtube or [here](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/) is the same video from expo doc if you want to read about it further. I hope this helps :)

after you do this fix you will run in to another error which you need to downgrade the installed node version to the current `LTS` version which at the time of this answer it is 18.17.0. to follow this fix please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-to-a-previous-node-version/76796786#76796786)

Comment: thanks brother it really worke for me now i am having no errors and ads are also showing fully fine. 

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because react-native-google-mobile-ads is not compatible with Expo. As per the official documentation:

"This module contains custom native code which is NOT supported by Expo Go"

More info [here](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads#installation)

Another easy way to fix the problem is to execute a build with:

```
npx expo run:android
```

After that, you can use expo normally